# Create an all-day event every month without weekends

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to have Google Apps Script create an event titled "Payday" for the 10th of every month, but if the 10th is Saturday or Sunday, then the event has to be created on the last weekday before the 10th (Friday).

So far, this is the closest I managed to get:

```js
var start = new Date();  // The event start date
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31];
var days = [
  CalendarApp.Weekday.SUNDAY,
  CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY,
  CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY,
  CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY,
  CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY,
  CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY,
  CalendarApp.Weekday.SATURDAY
];
var weekday = days[start.getDay()];
var monthday = start.getDate();
var mod = monthday % 7 - 1;
var good_days = numbers.slice(monthday-mod, monthday-mod+7)

var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence();
recurrence.addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(weekday).onlyOnMonthDays(good_days);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `So far, this is the closest I managed to get` what does this do as-is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function createNextMonthsTrigger() {
  let d = 10;
  const nmd = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, d).getDay();
  if (nmd == 6) {
    d = 9;
  } else if (nmd == 0) {
    d = 8;
  }
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => {
    if (t.getHandlerFunction() == 'createMyEvent') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createMyEvent').timeBased().onMonthDay(d).atHour(1).create();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Although, I am very bad at coding myself (unless I'm patching together a project with code from SO). So, I am not quite sure how I can make this trigger actually create an event on the days you specified for it to run on... So could you please update this with the 1-2 line that will make me an even?

Comment: Just name your function createMyEvent or replace createMyEvent with the name of your function.